# Objective-C bug passing NSArray to function

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

```
   `- (Lock *)lock
{
    if (!_lock){
        _lock = [[Lock alloc] init];
        _seqIndex = 0;
        _confIndex = 0;
        _confirmArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _lock;
}`

`- (IBAction)touchPicturePoint:(UIButton *)sender
{

    NSNumber *chosenPicturePoint = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[self.picturePoints indexOfObject:sender]];
    if (self.newLock){
        if (self.seqIndex < MAXSEQUENCE){
            [self.lock setLock:chosenPicturePoint
                          :self.username];
            self.seqIndex ++;
            if (self.seqIndex == MAXSEQUENCE){
                self.userPrompt.text = @"Please Confirm Your PicturePass";
            }
        } else {
            if (self.confIndex < MAXSEQUENCE){
                self.confirmArray[self.confIndex] = chosenPicturePoint;
                self.confIndex++;
            }
            if (self.confIndex == MAXSEQUENCE){
                if ([self.lock confirmLock:self.confirmArray
                                          :self.username]){
                    self.lock = nil;
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Register Success" sender:sender];
                } else {
                    self.userPrompt.text = @"PicturePass Mismatch! Please try again!";
                    [self.lock eraseLockFromUser:self.username];
                    self.lock = nil;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!self.newLock){
        if (self.confIndex < MAXSEQUENCE){
            self.confirmArray[self.confIndex] = chosenPicturePoint;
            self.confIndex++;
        }
        if (self.confIndex == MAXSEQUENCE){
            if ([self.lock confirmLock:self.confirmArray
                                      :self.username]){
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login Success" sender:sender];
            } else {
                self.userPrompt.text = @"Invalid PicturePass, try again!";
                self.lock = nil;
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

In the above code I am having a problem where in the "if (!self.newLock){" block it passes an empty array to [self.lock confirmLock] however in the "if (self.newLock)" I have seemingly identical code but it passes the array just as intended.

The code for confirmLock is:

```
`- (BOOL)confirmLock:(NSArray *)confirmArray
                    :(NSString *)username
{
    if (![confirmArray count]){
        NSLog(@"WTF");
        abort();
    }
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    Login *user = [self fetchUser:username
                                 :context];
    if (([user.point1 integerValue] == [confirmArray[0] integerValue])&&([user.point2 integerValue] == [confirmArray[1] integerValue])&&([user.point3 integerValue] == [confirmArray[2] integerValue])&&([user.point4 integerValue] == [confirmArray[3] integerValue])){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}`
```

Comment: Who creates `self.confirmArray`, where and when?

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. We need more info about the nature of confirmArray.

Comment: @Tommy @CrimsonChris I initialize confirmArray at in the - (Lock *)lock method, code looks like this 
`- (Lock *)lock
{
    if (!_lock){
        _lock = [[Lock alloc] init];
        _seqIndex = 0;
        _confIndex = 0;
        _confirmArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _lock;
}`

Comment: @user3348896 Edit your question to include this code.

Comment: @CrimsonChris okay I did

Comment: I don't see you adding anything to your confirm array. I would expect it to be empty based on the code provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard opening comment: parameters should be named in Objective-C. Leaving them unnamed is considered poor coding.

Paternalistic comments aside, this:

```
self.lock confirmLock:self.confirmArray
                                      :self.username
```

Effectively turns into:

```
objc_msgSend(self.lock, @selector(confirmLock::), self.confirmArray, self.username);
```

In C there is no defined evaluation order for parameters to a function. Therefore in Objective-C there is no defined evaluation order for either arguments to a method or any getters used in sending the message.

In your case, `self.confirmArray` may be called before `self.lock`. So you'd pass `nil`. As `[nil <anything>]` evaluates to zero, `[nil count]` evaluates to zero.

EDIT: and, per CrimsonChris' comment above, you also seem to create an empty array on purpose. So it's not surprising when it's subsequently empty, even if it gets through.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever seen a method with an unnamed parameter. Definitely a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just started learning a couple of weeks ago so a lot is foreign to me, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

your method confirmLock is with an unnamed parameter, change its parameter with name.you can try this.
for example :

- (BOOL)confirmLock:(NSArray *)confirmArray withname:(NSString *)username